# cannot load web.config in mstest

Tags: web-config, mstest

I need read connection string from web.config which in asp.net mvc project, but all i get are null. how can i obtain connection string in mstest, do i need additional configuration in some where?

Answer (score 2):

You can include the web.config file as part of the test project output by including the deployment item attribute in your test class:

```
[TestClass()]
[DeploymentItem("Web.Config")]
public class myClassTest
{
}
```

Then you should be able to retrieve your connection string as usual in the class you are trying to test: